# Solving an inequality with AM-GM

Tags: calculus, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> $X+Y>N$ and $$X+Y+2\sqrt{(X+13)(Y+26)}>-14$$ Find $N$.

Got really confused... Should I use AM-GM which $$2\sqrt{(X+13)(Y+26)}<(X+13)+(Y+26)$$ (since we want to minimize $M+N$) we maximize $$2\sqrt{(X+13)(Y+26)}$$? Got really confused. Please help!

Comment: What is an original problem?

Comment: what is $M$ in your quesiton?

Comment: Wait i don't really get it... What do you guys mean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $2(a^2+b^2)\geq(a+b)^2$, we obtain:
$$2(x+13+y+26)\geq\left(\sqrt{x+13}+\sqrt{y+26}\right)^2>25.$$
Thus, $x+y>-26.5$.

For $x\rightarrow-\frac{27}{4}$ and $y\rightarrow-\frac{79}{4}$ say that our estimation was exact.

Thus, a best $N=-26.5$.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a name for this inequality or is it just an transformation of other famous inequalities?

Comment: It's Cauchy-Schwarz: $(1+1)(a^2+b^2)\geq(1\cdot a+1\cdot b)^2=(a+b)^2$.

Comment: It is an off-shoot of the AM-GM since $2(a^2 + b^2) = a^2 + b^2 + (a^2 + b^2) \ge a^2 + b^2 + 2ab = (a + b)^2$

Comment: Thank you! Im a beginner in olympiad math and still trying to learn these inequalities